# Apache configuration error 403

Tags: linux, apache, http, rhel

I have followed this tutorial to configure http apache server:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/chap-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server.html

When I connected using

```
telnet localhost 12345
GET / HTTP/1.0
```

I got an error

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

and the default html of apache was listed below too.
I tried to configure the

> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

adding

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and also ran

```
chmod -R o+x /var/www/html
```

and I'm still getting the same error. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a file called index.html inside /var/www/html/ directory?
I would also suggest to check access and error logs files under /var/log/httpd directory

Comment: Also make sure that you have change the onwer of the `/var/www/html` to apache user. Code: `sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html -R`

Comment: He probably uses rhel/centos so the default apache user is apache and not www-data.

Comment: Now while this is working fine how do I make my website visible outside the server??

Comment: Do you have a public IP for your server?